# How can I generalize a conditional backfill?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this following dataframe:

| Track | Surface | FGrating | HorseId | Last FGrating at Sha Tin Grass | Last FGrating at Sha Tin Dirt | Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Happy Valley | grass | 97 | 22609 |  |  |  |
| Happy Valley | grass | 106 | 22609 |  |  | 97 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 104 | 22609 |  |  | 106 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 102 | 22609 |  |  | 104 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 95 | 22609 |  |  | 102 |
| Sha Tin | grass | 108 | 22609 |  |  |  |
| Sha Tin | grass | 104 | 22609 | 108 |  |  |
| Sha Tin | grass | 114 | 22609 | 104 |  |  |
| Sha Tin | dirt | 104 | 22609 |  |  |  |
| Sha Tin | grass | 101 | 22609 | 114 |  |  |
| Sha Tin | dirt | 92 | 22609 |  | 104 |  |
| Happy Valley | grass | 107 | 22609 |  |  | 95 |
| Sha Tin | grass | 102 | 22609 | 101 |  |  |
| Happy Valley | grass | 108 | 22609 |  |  | 107 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 105 | 22609 |  |  | 108 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 104 | 22609 |  |  | 105 |

This Dataframe can be obtained like this:

```
{'Track': {10153: 'Happy Valley', 10154: 'Happy Valley', 10155: 'Happy Valley', 10156: 'Happy Valley', 10157: 'Happy Valley', 10158: 'Sha Tin', 10159: 'Sha Tin', 10160: 'Sha Tin', 10161: 'Sha Tin', 10162: 'Sha Tin', 10163: 'Sha Tin', 10164: 'Happy Valley', 10165: 'Sha Tin', 10166: 'Happy Valley', 10167: 'Happy Valley', 10168: 'Happy Valley'}, 'Surface': {10153: 'Gress', 10154: 'Gress', 10155: 'Gress', 10156: 'Gress', 10157: 'Gress', 10158: 'Gress', 10159: 'Gress', 10160: 'Gress', 10161: 'Dirt', 10162: 'Gress', 10163: 'Dirt', 10164: 'Gress', 10165: 'Gress', 10166: 'Gress', 10167: 'Gress', 10168: 'Gress'}, 'FGrating': {10153: 97, 10154: 106, 10155: 104, 10156: 102, 10157: 95, 10158: 108, 10159: 104, 10160: 114, 10161: 104, 10162: 101, 10163: 92, 10164: 107, 10165: 102, 10166: 108, 10167: 105, 10168: 104}, 'HorseId': {10153: 22609, 10154: 22609, 10155: 22609, 10156: 22609, 10157: 22609, 10158: 22609, 10159: 22609, 10160: 22609, 10161: 22609, 10162: 22609, 10163: 22609, 10164: 22609, 10165: 22609, 10166: 22609, 10167: 22609, 10168: 22609}, 'Last FGrating at Sha-Tin Grass': {10153: nan, 10154: nan, 10155: nan, 10156: nan, 10157: nan, 10158: nan, 10159: 108.0, 10160: 104.0, 10161: nan, 10162: 114.0, 10163: nan, 10164: nan, 10165: 101.0, 10166: nan, 10167: nan, 10168: nan}, 'Last FGrating at Sha-Tin Dirt': {10153: nan, 10154: nan, 10155: nan, 10156: nan, 10157: nan, 10158: nan, 10159: nan, 10160: nan, 10161: nan, 10162: nan, 10163: 104.0, 10164: nan, 10165: nan, 10166: nan, 10167: nan, 10168: nan}, 'Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass': {10153: nan, 10154: 97.0, 10155: 106.0, 10156: 104.0, 10157: 102.0, 10158: nan, 10159: nan, 10160: nan, 10161: nan, 10162: nan, 10163: nan, 10164: 95.0, 10165: nan, 10166: 107.0, 10167: 108.0, 10168: 105.0}}
```

I am trying to achieve two interlinked goals:

**The first goal** is to complete the empty cells according to the following two rules:

1. If a horse never raced on a particular track before, then its 'Last FGrating at ' is 0;
2. If a horse previously raced on a particular track, then he races on another, the 'Last FGrating at ' gets the last value on that particular track, until he either comes back on it or the dataset ends.

What I am looking for is this:

| Track | Surface | FGrating | HorseId | Last FGrating at Sha Tin Grass | Last FGrating at Sha Tin Dirt | Last FGrating at Happy Valley Grass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Happy Valley | grass | 97 | 22609 | 0 (rule 1) | 0 (rule 1) | 0 (rule 1) |
| Happy Valley | grass | 106 | 22609 | 0 (rule 1) | 0 (rule 1) | 97 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 104 | 22609 | 0 (rule 1) | 0 (rule 1) | 106 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 102 | 22609 | 0 (rule 1) | 0 (rule 1) | 104 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 95 | 22609 | 0 (rule 1) | 0 (rule 1) | 102 |
| Sha Tin | grass | 108 | 22609 | 0 (rule 1) | 0 (rule 1) | 95 (rule 2) |
| Sha Tin | grass | 104 | 22609 | 108 | 0 (rule 1) | 95 (rule 2) |
| Sha Tin | grass | 114 | 22609 | 104 | 0 (rule 1) | 95 (rule 2) |
| Sha Tin | dirt | 104 | 22609 | 104 (rule 2) | 0 (rule 1) | 95 (rule 2) |
| Sha Tin | grass | 101 | 22609 | 114 | 0 (rule 1) | 95 (rule 2) |
| Sha Tin | dirt | 92 | 22609 | 114(rule 2) | 104 | 95 (rule 2) |
| Happy Valley | grass | 107 | 22609 | 114 (rule 2) | 104 (rule 2) | 95 |
| Sha Tin | grass | 102 | 22609 | 101 | 104 (rule 2) | 95 (rule 2) |
| Happy Valley | grass | 108 | 22609 | 101(rule 2) | 104 (rule 2) | 107 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 105 | 22609 | 101(rule 2) | 104 (rule 2) | 108 |
| Happy Valley | grass | 104 | 22609 | 101(rule 2) | 104 (rule 2) | 105 |

I want to do this for every `HorseId` so a `groupby` is in order.

**The second goal** is to generalized the way the first goal is achieved. What do I mean by that? First, no matter the track the horse is racing on, the process is the same. Second, this process can also be applied to other statistics (let's say *last position on a certain track*).

The code that I have so far is this:

```
def return_mask_and_text_from_tracks(data, track_no, metric):
    if track_no == 0:  # Sha Tin - grass
        mask = (data.Track == 'Sha Tin') & (data.Surface == 'Gress')
        text = str(metric) + ' at Sha-Tin Grass'
    if track_no == 1:  # Sha Tin - dirt
        mask = (data.Track == 'Sha Tin') & (data.Surface == 'Dirt')
        text = str(metric) + ' at Sha-Tin Dirt'
    if track_no == 2:  # Happy Valley - grass
        mask = (data.Track == 'Happy Valley') & (data.Surface == 'Gress')
        text = str(metric) + ' at Happy Valley Grass'
    return mask, text

def compute_last_fgrating(data, mask=''):
    if len(mask) == 0:
        return data.groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
    else:
        return data.loc[mask][['HorseId', 'FGrating']].groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].apply(
            lambda x: x.shift(1))

for i in range(3):
    mask, text = return_mask_and_text_from_tracks(featured_data, i, 'Last FGrating')
    featured_data[text] = compute_last_fgrating(featured_data, mask=mask)
    idx = [ser.index[0] for _, ser in featured_data.groupby('HorseId')[text] if pd.isna(ser.iat[0])]
    featured_data.loc[idx, text] = 0
    featured_data[text] = featured_data[text].fillna(method='bfill')
```

I would be very nice if I could do this.

Can you help?

Comment: please paste your dataframe in as df.to_dict(), or something similar? your dataframe isn't easily reproducible. thank you.